# Leetcode question 26. I can't seem to return the right answer

Tags: java

> Given an integer array nums sorted in non-decreasing order, remove the duplicates in-place such that each unique element appears only once. The relative order of the elements should be kept the same. Then return the number of unique elements in nums.
>
> Consider the number of unique elements of nums be k, to get accepted, you need to do the following things:
>
> Change the array nums such that the first k elements of nums contain the unique elements in the order they were present in nums initially. The remaining elements of nums are not important as well as the size of nums.
> Return k.

My code

```
class Solution {
    int j = 0;
    public int removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {

        int[] newArr = new int[nums.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++){
            Arrays.sort(nums);
            if (nums[i] != nums[i+1] ) {
                newArr[j] = nums[i];
                j++;          
            }

        }

        newArr[j] = nums[nums.length - 1];
        j++;

        return j;
    }
}
```

I tried everything I could think of. Somehow my return output is wrong.

The first test case is `nums = [1,1,2]`

My output `[1,1]`

What is actual expected `[1,2]`

Comment: It says to change in place. That's the first problem. The array is also already sorted.

Comment: They probably expect you to do something like this: When a duplicate is found, move everything past the dup down by one slot.

Comment: You can't just automatically add the last element anyway when that's a dup itself.

Comment: The reason it shows output as `[1,1]` is because that's still the contents of the original array not the new one.

Comment: Alright I did a for loop to copy all the element in newArr to nums. And its still has the same output. For refrence                                                                                       
       for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
          nums[i] = newArr[i];

        }

Comment: You don't need the 2nd array at all. You can solve this with a single array, moving numbers in place.

Comment: I agree that copying the elements over should have given different output.